# Lua coroutine.yield(-1)'s meaning?

Tags: lua, coroutine

What does `coroutine.yield(-1)` mean? I don't understand `-1` here.

code piece and out put is:

```
> function odd(x)
>>   print('A: odd', x)
>>   coroutine.yield(x)
>>   print('B: odd', x)
>> end
>
> function even(x)
>>   print('C: even', x)
>>   if x==2 then return x end
>>   print('D: even ', x)
>> end
>
> co = coroutine.create(
>>   function (x)
>>     for i=1,x do
>>       if i==3 then coroutine.yield(-1) end
>>       if i % 2 == 0 then even(i) else odd(i) end
>>     end
>>   end)
>
> count = 1
> while coroutine.status(co) ~= 'dead' do
>>   print('----', count) ; count = count+1
>>   errorfree, value = coroutine.resume(co, 5)
>>   print('E: errorfree, value, status', errorfree, value, coroutine.status(co))
>> end
----    1
A: odd  1
E: errorfree, value, status     true    1       suspended
----    2
B: odd  1
C: even 2
E: errorfree, value, status     true    -1      suspended
----    3
A: odd  3
E: errorfree, value, status     true    3       suspended
----    4
B: odd  3
C: even 4
D: even         4
A: odd  5
E: errorfree, value, status     true    5       suspended
----    5
B: odd  5
E: errorfree, value, status     true    nil     dead
>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any arguments passed to the corresponding `coroutine.yield` are returned by `coroutine.resume`. So `-1` in `coroutine.yield(-1)` here is nothing special, it's similar to `coroutine.yield(x)` in the function `odd(x)`.

It is executed when `counter` is `2` and `i` is `3`. The corresponding output is:

```
----    2
B: odd  1
C: even 2
E: errorfree, value, status     true    -1      suspended
```

After `ture` which indicates no error, see the `-1` here? That's the value from the call to `coroutine.yield(-1)`, it ended up as a return value of `coroutine.resume`.

For the similar reason, the other return values of `coroutine.resume` are `1`, `3` and `5`, all coming from `coroutine.yield(x)` in the function `odd(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

coroutine.yield (···)

Suspends the execution of the calling coroutine. The coroutine cannot be running a C function, a metamethod, or an iterator. **Any arguments to yield are passed as extra results to resume.**

http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-coroutine.yield

So in other words the `-1` could have been anything or even multiple values and how those values are used is up to the programmer.